# Android - VideoView, getting current position as video is playing?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a VideoView that plays from internal memory. While my video is playing the VideoView logs `MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)`. I have an onErrorListener attached to the VideoView from where I'd like to manage this error. What I am aiming to do, is to get the last position (from `getCurrentPosition()`) and start my player again from that position, using `seekTo(int position)`. My video file is valid (verified by playing on other players). My problem now is to get the last valid position from VideoView. Calling `getCurrentPosition()` from onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) returns 0 when I do `mp.getCurrentPosition / mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()` (quite rightly so). How do I keep tracking the current position of the player while it is playing ?

Here is my code:

```
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                switch (what) {
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                        Log.v("error", "media error unknown");
                        mediaErrorExtra(mp, extra, path);
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                        Log.v("error", "media error server died");
                        mediaErrorExtra(mp, extra, path);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

private void mediaErrorExtra(MediaPlayer mp, int extra, String path){
        switch(extra){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:

                if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                    Integer currentposition = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                    if(currentposition != null){
                        Log.v("currentpos",Integer.toString(currentposition));
                    }
                    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
                    mVideoView.start();
                    //mVideoView.seekTo(currentposition);
                }
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
                Log.v("error extra","media error malformed");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
                Log.v("error extra","media error unsupported");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
                Log.v("error extra","media error timed out");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively is there any listener that provides the current position of the player while it is playing ? I could use a `while(isPlaying()){int currentposition = mVideoView.getCurrrentPosition()}` but I suppose this is a bad way of going about things. Any suggestion would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question:

A `ScheduledExecutorService` helped solve this:

Here's how I get the current position as the player plays:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService mScheduledExecutorService;
    int mCurrentposition = 0;
    Runnable UpdateCurrentPosition = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCurrentposition = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){
        ...
        mScheduledExecutorService = new ScheduledExecutor(1);

        mScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mVideoView.post(UpdateCurrentPosition);
            }
        },3000,1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: val service: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1) can work

Answer (score 1):

I show handler which i used...

```
        private double currentTime = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    //update Seekbar on UI thread
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.postDelayedUpdateProgress 100);
        }
    }

 private Runnable UpdateProgress = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         currentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         txt.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
```

You should use handler..

Comment: According to your code, you'll be updating the seekbar even after the video stops. You should remove `Runnable` from handler on video stop.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the `while` thing, but it will require a little more refining, because the while will probably block the UI entirely.

So what you should do is use a `Handler` that will trigger a check every 1 second for the `MediaPlayer` position, I think, 1 sec is quite reasonable.

I've used this approach to implement a custom `SeekBar` for the MediaPlayer and it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks for this, I do get the currentposition this way but now MediaController's seek bar does not show up.. Need to get around that too...

Answer (score 0):

```
private int time = 0;

private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduledExecutorService;
Runnable getPositionVideo = () -> {
    time = binding.videoView.getCurrentPosition();

};


   binding.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> {
        binding.videoView.seekTo(position);
        binding.videoView.start();
        mScheduledExecutorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        mScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
            runOnUiThread(getPositionVideo);
            MediaControllerExitFullScreen.init(video_url, time);
        }, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```